# Why is IntelliJ not showing the project structure?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

Just tried to create a JAR with IntelliJ as always. Now IntelliJ doesn't show the project structure. It looks like this (I can't post an image, because Stackoverlow says I need "at least 10 reputation to post images"):

MyProject.iml

pom.xml

External Libraries

There are no classes or anything, that are the only files shown in tab "Project". Why? Version is 13.1.5
I checked all view options with an older project which does not have this problem after creating a jar, everthing is fine. First time that is occurs for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using version 12.1.4

You can create a new project File -> Import Module -> and importing the older project.

Import Project also works as well.

Comment: Well... I don't understand this, but it fixes the problem :D